# ¿Cómo realizar una búsqueda anidada?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algoritmos

Soy nuevo en *Rails*, quiero realizar una consulta al mismo tiempo en 3 tablas distintas, quiero que me dé como título el período, y que me arroje los campos de las otras dos tablas con sus datos respectivos, y hasta ahora solo logro que me arroje los de una sola tabla.

El código es el siguiente:

```
def consulta
  @q = params[:q]
  if @q
    @periodo = Periodo.find( @q)
    @pago = Paga.where(:periodo_id => @q)
    @f = params[:figura_id]
    @figuras = Figura.where(:id => @f)     '
  else
    @periodo = Periodo.all
  end
end
```

Formulario de la búsqueda:

```
<form>
Periodo
<input name="q" <%= @q %>>
<button type="submit">Buscar</button>
</form>

<% if @q  %>
<center><h1><%= @periodo.Anio %> <%= @periodo.Mes %></h1></center>
  <%for pago in @pago%> <%for figura in @figuras%>
    <%= @pago.figura_id %><%= pago.Monto %><%= pago.Descripcion %> <%= figura.Nombre %> </br>
  <%end%>
  <%end%>   
<% end %>
```

Solo me arroja el período y los pagos que se han realizado, pero los datos de la tercera tabla no me los enlista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad esto iba mas como comentario, pero tu código tiene bastantes detalles que quisiera darte a conocer:

- El código que pusiste no es válido, tiene una comilla al final de `@figuras = Figura.where(:id => @f)     '`
- En lo poco que pusiste de código, asumo que tu modelo `Periodo` tiene `has_many :pagas`, ¿cierto? entonces no debería ser necesario que llames a `@pago = Paga.where(:periodo_id => @q)`, ya que luego con solo llamar a `@periodo.pagas` en tu template debería ser suficiente para traer todas las pagas asociadas a ese periodo.
- En general es mala práctica en ruby [empezar tus nombres de atributos con mayúscula](https://github.com/alemohamad/ruby-style-guide/blob/master/README-esLA.md#nombres), como en `@periodo.Anio` o `@periodo.Mes`, supongo aún estás a tiempo de cambiarlo, así que de ser posible hazlo.
- Ten cuidado con lo que estás haciendo en `<input name="q" <%= @q %>>`, que aparte de estar mal formado ese input, estás eventualmente haciendo vulnerable tu aplicación ya que `@q = params[:q]` y en los parámetros uno podría pasar cualquier valor que eventualmente podría conllevar a un [ataque XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) en tu aplicación.
- A pesar de que en `<%for pago in @pago%>` son dos variables distintas, acostumbrate a ponerle nombres distintos, ya que un código así es demasiado susceptible a que genere bugs por el solo hecho de que olvidaste poner una `@` cuando se requería o la pusiste cuando no se debía. Con que la variable del controlador venga como `@pagos` debería ser suficiente.

Ahora, respecto a tu problema en sí:

- ¿te aseguraste que vaya un valor valido en `params[:figura_id]`? revisa tu terminal donde estás ejecutando `rails s` para ver que parámetros estás enviando.
- ¿Has confirmado que `Figura.where(:id => @f)` efectivamente está retornando algo?. Ejecuta la consulta en una consola de rails y verifica que efectivamente te este retornando algo cuando le pasas los parámetros que le estás enviando.

Comment: muchas gracias por tus observaciones! :D y si se que tengo muchos detalles que aun tengo que resolver, como te comento es mi primer aplicacion y agradesco tu tiempo al mostrarme un mejor camino, ahora respecto a params[:figura_id], no me arroja nada, no logro sacar del for pago in @pago este valor, esa es mi duda realmente, la tabla pago tiene los campos figura_id, periodo_id, monto y descripcion, y aun asi no logro que params[figura_id] tome algun valor

Comment: @AbrahamRamos pero si no te está llegando `figura_id` al controlador, es porque no lo estás enviando por el lado de la vista. Publica el código donde supuestamente está yendo `figura_id` hacia el controlador, sino no hay como ayudarte

Comment: ese es el detalle no se como sacar del for este campo que es figuras_id es lo que quiero saber para poder enviarlo a el controlador

Comment: el formulario de la busqueda es es mi vista completa, de aqui he intentado enviar :figuras_id, pero no puedo sacarla de el for.

Comment: solucionado con un join muchas gracias! :D